# Tables inside a div? IE7 compatability issue - looking for a resource to expand knowledge on how to deal with IE7 problems

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I'm currently doing the redesign for this site: http://www.palosverdes.com/rpv2012/ and have run into a problem with repeating a gradient inside a div (cnews).  The issue is that when the gradient is repeated on IE7, there is a color problem. It almost seems as if the blue on the image is lightened somehow.  When I set the attribute to no-repeat, I don't get the rounded edges effect I'd like the achieve.

Here's the code in question:

```
<div class="box-noshadow" id="cnews">
<div id="spotlight">
</div><!--spotlight-->
<div onmouseout="document.getElementById('stop').start();" onmouseover="document.getElementById('stop').stop();" id="stopmarquee">
<div align="center" id="toptitle">
CITY NEWS &amp; EVENTS
</div><!--toptitle-->
<div id="cnewscontainer">
<iframe align="middle" width="400px" scrolling="no" height="100px" frameborder="0" src="scroll_file_b/break2.cfm"></iframe>
</div><!--cnewscontainer-->
</div><!--stopmarquee-->
</div><!--cnews-->
```

and the relevant CSS:

```
#cnews {
width: 100%;
background-image:url(images/cnews-back.jpg);
float: left;
padding: 5px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
overflow:hidden;}

#spotlight {
width: 50%;
height: 200px;
background-color: yellow;
float: right;
padding: 5px;}

.box {-moz-border-radius: 15px; /* Firefox */
-webkit-border-radius: 15px; /* Safari and Chrome */
border-radius: 15px; /* Opera 10.5+, future browsers, and now also Internet Explorer 6+ using IE-CSS3 */
-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px #000; /* Firefox */
-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px #000; /* Safari and Chrome */
box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px #000; /* Opera 10.5+, future browsers and IE6+ using IE-CSS3 */
behavior: url(PIE.htc); /* This lets IE know to call the script on all elements which get the 'box' class */}
```

What solution can I pursue that will allow this to still render correctly in modern browsers as well?  Should I use IE7-specific CSS?

Also, where can I look to see what HTML/CSS ie7 has problems interpreting compared to modern browsers?

Comment: The "lightened" blue is actually the background image repeating because the containing div is stretching downwards. If you set "background-repeat: repeat-x;" you will see what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `width:50%` on your `stopmarquee` is causing that item to drop down lower in IE7, instead of rising up next to the right floated `spotlight` div. This is causing your `cnews` container to expand down further, which is then causing your background image to repeat in the 'y' direction (like 3rror404 stated in his comment).

Your background image itself has a color shift within it, so that the top of the image is lighter than the lower part of the image, thus you are getting a lighter look when the image repeats in the 'y' direction.

You can correct the `stopmarquee` position by changing to `width: 49%` (which I don't think will hurt your layout), and that will probably resolve your issue. Otherwise, make the background image a solid color so that a repeat does not cause the issue.

Comment: Thank you.  I removed it completely instead, which has fixed it.